# MediaWiki:Noarticletext page not shown in one language

Tags: mediawiki

I have two MediaWiki wiki's and with both I've implemented a [MediaWiki:Noarticletext](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Noarticletext) system message, both with same text.

One wiki shows the text of that system message for a not existing page (as logged in user), the other shows '*There is currently no text in this page (for a not existing page, as logged in user). You can search for this page title in other pages, search the related logs, or edit this page*'.

What's the difference? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [$wgUseDatabaseMessages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseDatabaseMessages)?

Comment: Nope, same value. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found: had something to do with language settings, so using Dutch in one wiki, English in second wiki. Implementing `MediaWiki:Noarticletext/en` did the trick.

Comment: This is a correct workaround for the bug https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T50956